# Crawling video with apache nutch

Tags: apache, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

How to fetch video tag like this with Apache Nutch :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Apache nutch can fetch image tag but didn't work in video source. Can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks for helping

Comment: video link is like URL/video/video.mp4 or URL/video/video.ogg. So, use their src attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already fix this problem by adding source tag on plugin parse-html (DOMContentUtils.java)

```
linkParams.put("frame", new LinkParams("frame", "src", 0));
linkParams.put("iframe", new LinkParams("iframe", "src", 0));
linkParams.put("script", new LinkParams("script", "src", 0));
linkParams.put("link", new LinkParams("link", "href", 0));
linkParams.put("img", new LinkParams("img", "src", 0));
linkParams.put("source", new LinkParams("source", "src", 0))
```

then rebuild with ant.

hope its helpful for the other

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert this in **parse-plugins.xml.**

```
<mimeType name="video/mp4">
    <plugin id="parse-tika" />
</mimeType>

<mimeType name="video/ogg">
    <plugin id="parse-tika" />
</mimeType>
```

And add parse-tika in plugin includes property of **nutch-site.xml**.

```
<property>
        <name>plugin.includes</name>
        <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>

    </property>
```

Comment: Thanks rocksta for helping!